# Generics functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was reading this [article](https://altrim.io/posts/axios-http-client-using-typescript) about how to use Axios with TypeScript and I had a question about the methods declaration, for example:

```
  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.get<T, R>(url, config);
  }

  delete<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    return this.http.delete<T, R>(url, config);
  }
```

Now, what I miss to understand is the this syntax:

```
<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>
```

Why is the `T` equal to `any`, isn't it the concept of Generics that `T` can be anything? Why do I need to specify it? Is it for readability?
Also why is `R` equals `AxiosResponse<T>`? Couldn't I just say that the return type of the function is `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>`, is it also the sake of writing less code in the return type?

Comment: Those are defaults. It's like if you write `function(x: number = 1) { ... }`, it doesn't mean `x` has to be 1, it means that `x` is 1 unless you say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) that are used when the type isn't specified and can't be inferred. (Kind of like function parameter defaults, `function foo(a = 42)` says `a` is `42` if [loosely speaking] it's not provided.)

> ...isn't it the concept of Generics that `T` can be anything?

Not necessarily, generic type parameters can be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), but yes in this case.

> Why do I need to specify it?

You don't need to (but you can), there's a default if you don't and it can't be inferred from the call site. If the `= any` weren't there, then you *would* have to specify it.

> Also why is `R` equals `AxiosResponse<T>`? Couldn't I just say that the return type of the function is `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>`...

It's simpler to use (and probably better for inference) if you specify the type of what you're expecting in the response, without the `Promise` wrapper on it.

```
const thingy = await axios.get<ThingyType>("...");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to clarify something, in the article he uses the return type as such `func <T= any, R = AxiosPromise<T>>(...args):Promise<R> {...}`
What was I  wondering about the `R` is if it could've also be written as such: 
`func <T= any>(...args):Promise<AxiosPromise<T>> {...}`?

Comment: @Keselme - That would mean something different. Again, `AxiosPromise<T>` is just the *default* for `R` if `R` isn't specified. But the way the article has it, the caller can specify `R` to be something other than `AxiosPromise<T>`. (I find it odd that the article seems to be wrapping a promise [`AxiosPromise`] in a promise [`Promise`], but...) FWIW, beware that the bar for posting an article on the web is *really low* and the quality varies. That article may be fantastic (I haven't read it and don't know the author), but there are definitely very poor ones out there...